# On C# escape curly braces and a backslash after

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

I am trying to format a text so I can provide a template some RFT text.

My string is declared with the stringformater as:

```
var fullTitleString = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            "{{\\Test",
            title,
            filterName);
```

But I keep obtaining a string as "{\Test". Using a single backslash results on errors at it does not understand the \T escaped character.

Doing @"{{\Test" also yields "{\Test". I have looked over the MSDN documentation and other questions where they tell to use another backslash as escaping character, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What are you *trying* to achieve? And why are you passing in `title` and `filterName` when your format string doesn't include `{0}` or `{1}`? This question is very unclear at the moment. Fundamentally you need to differentiate between escaping at the C# string literal level and escaping at the `string.Format` level though.

Comment: Why are you using string.Format? I don't see any formating operation. Are you concatenating text? In that case you can use string.Concat and don't need to escape curly braces.

Comment: To be completely honest with you I am the scholar apprentice at the office so I have no idea about the reasons of using this implementation.

I forgot to mention, but the whole string should have title and filterName added on {0} {1} but that part is already solved, and as the string is really long and my only issue is with the backslashes I omitted most of it.

Answer (score 4):

There are two levevls of escaping here:

**1. Escaping string literals**

In c# strings, a backslash (`\`) is used as special character and needs to be escaped by another `\`. So if your resulting string should look like `\\uncpath\folder` your string literal should be `var s = "\\\\uncpath\\folder"`.

**2. Escape format strings**

`string.Format` uses curly braces for place holders, so you need to escape them with extra braces.

So let's say you have

```
string title = "myTitle";
string filterName = "filter";
```

then

```
string.Format("{{\\Test {0}, {1}}}", title, filterName);
```

results in

```
{\Test myTitle, filter}
```

If you want two curly braces at the beginning, you need to put four in your format string:

```
string.Format("{{{{\\Test {0}, {1}}}", title, filterName);
```

results in

```
{{\Test myTitle, filter}
```

If you provide a clear example of what you are trying to achieve, I may tell you the correct format string.

*Side note: In C# 6 the last example could also be `$"{{{{\\Test {title}, {filterName}}}"` (using string interpolation without explicitly calling `string.Format`)*

**NOTE:** The Visual Studio debugger always shows the unescaped string literal. So if you declare a string like `string s = "\\"` you will see both backslashes in your debugger windows, but if you `Console.WriteLine(s)` only one backslash will be written to console.

Comment: I would like to obtain something similar to

`{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang3082\b\fs18 title:\b0  filterName\cf0\par}` 

as an output, but what I keep obtaining is this same text but with double backslashes, even that I am escaping them by adding extra ones.

Comment: @janonespe Do you see this in debugger or as output? Note that the debugger shows strings as literals, so it will show "\\" where a real output would show "\".

Comment: I was seeing at the debugger indeed. I have to check with the output, but it seems that it was the main issue, thanks a lot!